# Typescript: converting an array to another array with different type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects that corresponds to one interface, and I'm using a function that takes this kind of array and spits a different array of objects that corresponds to another interface

It can look something like this:

```
export const filterPagesById = (
  items: FirstInterface[],
  ids: string[],
): SecondInterface[] => items.filter((route) => ids.includes(route.id));
```

Typescript yells at me that type `FirstInterface[]` is not assignable to `SecondInterface[]`.

The function does work properly and the array is transformed to the correct SecondInterface type. How can I "promise" Typescript that the function will indeed return the correct type?

Comment: you can specify type conversion,that might help

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how you would do that?

Comment: Could you share the relationship between `FirstInterface` and `SecondInterface`? There might be some other things you can do if the two are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that the filter condition will keep only `SecondInterface[]` items you can use [casting](https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_casting.php):

```
export const filterPagesById = (
  items: FirstInterface[],
  ids: string[],
): SecondInterface[] => items.filter((route) => ids.includes(route.id)) as SecondInterface[];
```

Comment: Oh alright yes that's what I tried now thanks!

Comment: Type assertions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript won't have any problem with this:

```
interface FirstInterface {
  id: string
}

interface SecondInterface {
  id: string
}

const filterPagesById = (
  items: FirstInterface[],
  ids: string[],
): SecondInterface[] => items.filter((route) => ids.includes(route.id));
```

That's because it knows the two interfaces/types overlap.

There's a reason TypeScript is complaining and you should try to get to the bottom of that instead of using type assertions if you can, because type assertions aren't type safe.

Can you share the two types `FirstInterface` and `SecondInterface`?